# How to call specific method of PHP with CURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I m developing an API.In this API i need to modify some of users data who have already singup..(basically update method which is in **dosomething.php** page).

So i know about PUT method..but i m having more than one method for user updates..

so my Question is how do i make my dosomething.php page understand that which update method is being called by curl.

My curl url is

> http://localhost/apitest/dosomething.php

.

Should i get data from curl request and than use **switch case in dosomething.php** page?
Help me which is proper way to do.

---

now said by Daniel A. White can i do like this
My curl url
http://localhost/apitest/dosomething.php?method=updatemobileno

and than get this variable value in php and use it to select my specific method??

Comment: could you put a query string on it? or look at the user agent?

Comment: Are you confusing HTTP methods (verbs) with PHP methods (functions)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call **directly** a **PHP** method with a `GET`/`POST`/`PUT` **HTTP request**. You need to call a **PHP** script, and then route to the appropriate method depending on what you want.

So, you would invoke **curl** with something like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost/apitest/dosomething.php
```

Then, `dosomething.php` will be a **PHP** script receiving your **HTTP request**, and inside of it, you can call the appropriate method:

```
<?php
    function f_put() {
       // put magic here
    }
    function f_post() {
       // post magic here
    }
    function f_get() {
       // get magic here
    }


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
        f_get();
    } else if if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        f_post();
    } else if if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        f_put();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Mr Pablo Santa i have a doubt with your ans when i m updating i should use PUT so now based on your ans how can i differentiate between which update method to call after having this $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT' as i have more than 1 update methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have an obscure idea ,but it is not advised to use this(someone please?).

Consider this curl post request with

```
curl --data "func=fn_name&param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com/x.php
```

Now in the file x.php

```
function fn1($p,$q)
{ 
}
function fn2($a,$b)
{
}
if($_POST['func']=="fn1")
{
    fn1($_POST['param1'],$_POST['param2'])
}

if($_POST['func']=="fn2")
{
    fn2($_POST['param1'],$_POST['param2'])
}
```